# Missing table after 'reverse engineer code first' using Entity Framework Power Tools in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am missing one table from my database after running a 'Reverse engineer code first'. **The action completes successfully and if not for the missing table everything would be fine.**

I am using VS2012 and ASP.NET MVC 4 with Entity Framework 5.0 and Power Tools Beta 3.
On the database side the server is running SQL server 2005.

The missing table is `'webpages_UsersInRoles'` which as far as I know is a standard table created by default as it holds relational information about the standard membership roles in MVC.

Can anyone either shed any light as to why it is not being included in the dbcontext creation OR how I can add it to the import process to make sure it is being included.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the only table that's missing? Did it reverse engineer the other standard Membership tables like aspnet_Users?

Comment: Other standard membership tables have all been imported correctly, e.g.
`webpages_Membership`
`webpages_OAuthMembership`
`webpages_Roles`